# Why the displacement option in the material panel is missing?

Tags: materials, normal-map, displacement, bump

I have seen this option (in displacement - bump only) in a youtube video but I can't find it under my settings panel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Specific title, preferably a question please. Also consider to accept Robert's answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 10):

The *Settings* panel from your first screenshot is from the *Cycles* render engine. The second screenshot shows a project where *Eevee* is the current render engine.

The render engine can be changed in the *Render Properties* tab.

[image: Render engine]